# Julia - How to open a file using a Cmd type?

Tags: file, cmd, julia

I am trying to physically open a file (not to read the data but just open it in windows) in Julia.

I have tried using `` run(`test.txt`) `` but it could not find the file. Then I realized that I needed a command in front so I tried `` run(`run test.txt`) ``. This seems to find the file but the file crashes immediately upon startup. How should I go about opening this file? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your concept of *"opening a file"* is not clear, I assume that you want to see the file in an external editor. This will work on Windows:

```
julia> open("file.txt","w") do f
       print(f,"Hello world!\r\nGood day to you\r\n")
       end

julia> p = run(`notepad file.txt`,wait=false)
Process(`notepad file.txt`, ProcessRunning)
```